# selecting images in javascript

Tags: javascript

I dont know javascript very well, I want to ask how to select images and show them on my screen. I want to make a list of images, then I will choose one of them and when I press a button show I want to demonstrate it. Is it possible in js?

Comment: your question is quite unspecific. what are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

the simplest way would be to define a  tag and every link should change the source attribute of this.

it could be like following

```
<img id="cimg" src="img.jpg">
<a href="javascript:changepic('img2.jpg')">Img 2</a>
```

and JS:

```
function changepic(url) {
  document.getElementById("cimg").setAttribute("src", url);
}
```

but for really cool looking you should use e.g. jquery and a jquery plugin...

Answer (score 1):

i think you want to make some kind of gallery?

http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2011/08/25-jquery-image-galleries-and-slideshow-plugins/ are listed some gallery plugins